# When refresh/reload a table, can't concatenate some lines in a td

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

In a web page I refresh/reload a div, every minute, with content which is in a text file. This part of the code is working.

The problem is that in the table, when I have severals lines with in the first column have the same content, I need to concatenate it.

Example that I want:

[image: table displayed correctly]

Example that I have after the table data reload:

[image: table not displayed correctly]

Here the code in order to reload my table/div every minute:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); 
            setInterval(function() {
                    $('#datatable-1_wrapper').load('bodytest.txt');

                      //part of code that worked when i load the entire page, but not work in this setInterval method
                      var names = {}, td, cname, p;
                      $('#t1').find('tr').each(function(){
                        if((td = $(this).find('td').get(0)) && (cname = td.className)){
                          var cnames = cname.split(' ');
                          names[cnames[0]] = names[cnames[0]]? names[cnames[0]] + 1 : 1;
                        } 
                      });
                      for (p in names){
                        if(names[p] > 1){
                          $('.' + p + ':gt(0)').remove();
                          $('.' + p).attr('rowspan', names[p]);
                        }
                     }

        }, 10000);  
});
```

Can you explain me why the part of the code which concatenate the lines in one td is working when i load the page but not in the refresh method?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just guessing here, but it looks like your code runs too soon; consider this instead:

```
$('#datatable-1_wrapper').load('bodytest.txt', function() {
    // loaded, now do the rest of your code
});
```

The inner function will get called once the wrapper has been loaded.

Comment: Oohh, you're right!
indead it was the cause, thanks!